# Linkerd - no controller pods after upgrade ( helm upgrade )

Tags: helm3, linkerd

Today I upgraded linkerd from 2.10 to 2.11, but after the upgrade it looks like my controller pod is no longer there,

I upgraded with

```
helm upgrade --namespace v3-mainapp linkerd2 linkerd/linkerd2 --atomic
```

and it gave me

```
Release "linkerd2" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: linkerd2
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Dec 30 07:42:15 2021
NAMESPACE: v3-mainapp
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 3
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
The Linkerd control plane was successfully installed 

To help you manage your Linkerd service mesh you can install the Linkerd CLI by running:

  curl -sL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh

Alternatively, you can download the CLI directly via the Linkerd releases page:

  https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/releases/

To make sure everything works as expected, run the following:

  linkerd check

Linkerd Viz extension can be installed by running:

  linkerd viz install | kubectl apply -f -
```

But when I run `linkerd check` it gives me an error about `No running pods for "controller"` and  `kubectl get po --all-namespaces --selector linkerd.io/control-plane-component=controller` returns no resources

I have attempted to re-do the upgrade, but same results

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out, It looks like my linkerd cli was out of date, and they changed how the checks where, I ran

`curl -sL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh`

again and now the control plane is passing